# How to call search term variable in functions.php?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to call a variable in `functions.php` file but it does not work for some reason. From what I have read, the default method to call search word in Wordpress is done using the following method. It is working fine in `search.php` but not in `functions.php`

```
<?php $search_query = get_search_query(); ?>
<div align="center">
<?php echo $search_query ?>
</div>
```

I am making use of the same in an array as follows in `functions.php` file but it is not being called.

This does not work:

```
<?php
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback_search() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts_search', 'security');
    $paged_search = $_POST['page'];
    $args_search = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '20',
        's' => $search_query,
        'paged' => $paged_search,
    );
    $my_posts_search = new WP_Query( $args_search );
    if ( $my_posts_search->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts_search->have_posts() ) : $my_posts_search->the_post() ?>
```

But when I hard code the search term "Bangalore" in the code, it is working

```
<?php
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback_search() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts_search', 'security');
    $paged_search = $_POST['page'];
    $args_search = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '20',
        's' => 'Bangalore',
        'paged' => $paged_search,
    );
    $my_posts_search = new WP_Query( $args_search );
    if ( $my_posts_search->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts_search->have_posts() ) : $my_posts_search->the_post() ?>
```

How do I make it work for all keywords?

This is the script that calls this post 
This script runs in search.php to call more posts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {

    var data = {
        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax_search',
        'page': page,
        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts_search"); ?>'
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $('.my-posts').append(response);
        page++;
    });
});
});

</script>
```

The Search Term Comes From This Search From

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" target="_self">
<div>
<input style="text-align:center;width:100%;margin:0 0 12px; 0;border-color:#4a235a;color:#000000;" placeholder='Eg:Location,Skill,Company' class="text" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
</div> 
<div>
<input type="submit" style="text-align:center;margin:0 0 0 0;width:100%;border:1.5px solid;border-color:grey;background-color:#4a235a;color:#f4511e;" class="submit button" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Search');?>" />
</div>
</form>
```

Please Let Me Know If You Need The Complete Code From search.php and functions.php file . Thanks for any input and help.

Comment: Please share the script the calls this function.

Comment: please check the updated post for script

Comment: Where the search term should come from? Is there a form in this page? If yes, please add its code as well.

Comment: Sure I am adding the code now

Comment: Great, added an answer. Should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Process:**

1. The visitor writes the search term and clicks the search button
2. Using jQuery we will access the search term and send it with our request to the PHP script
3. In the PHP function we will get the search term and use the "s" parameter in our args array for WP_Query.

**Access the search term with jQuery**

```
$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {

    var data = {
        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax_search',
        'page': page,
        'searchTerm': $('#s').val(), //Get the search term.
        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts_search"); ?>'
    }
```

**Update your PHP code:**

```
$paged_search = $_POST['page'];
$search_term = esc_attr($_POST['searchTerm']);
$args_search = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
    's' => $search_term,
    'paged' => $paged_search,
);
```

Comment: Try to debug it and find why not. in your jquery, use "console.debug($('#s').val());" and in your PHP write "var_dump($search_term);", then use your console (developers tools) to see the output of those variables, and update me.

Comment: the logic you are using is right but still it is not working

Comment: I'm aware of that :) Follow my debug instructions.

Comment: I am updating function.php and search.php code here. Kindly check and let me know about the required changes that will make it work.

Comment: My previous comment was about debugging the code and understanding where the problem is. I need the output of the console in order to know it.

Comment: These are the changes that i have made and shared the code here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266343/unable-to-call-search-term-in-functions-php-from-search-php-searchfrom-php-in

Comment: Made it work .. Thank you for the help 
'searchTerm': $('#s').val()
was replaced By
'searchTerm': '<?php echo $search_query ?>'
this works flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the variable into your function for it to be available in that function.

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback_search($searchInput) {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts_search', 'security');
    $paged_search = $_POST['page'];
    $args_search = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '20',
        's' => $searchInput,
        'paged' => $paged_search,
```

And when you call the function, you put in your $search_query variable.

```
load_posts_by_ajax_search($search_query)
```

Comment: Made it work .. Thank you for the help 
'searchTerm': $('#s').val()
was replaced By
'searchTerm': '<?php echo $search_query ?>'
this works flawlessly

Comment: ah... I see.. thats great that you got it working. :)